# On opening new tab the previous tab freezes in Angular4

Tags: angular4-router

I am using router.navigate in Angular4, but the problem with this is on opening the new tab the previous tab freezes for seconds. In other words, I cannot perform any operation on the first tab till the newly opened tab gets the data.

Comment: please show your code so some one help you better. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: here what I am using this.router.navigate(['route', datavariable]);

Comment: If you have code to show, please **edit your question**, rather than adding code snippets to the comments. Proper code formatting tools are available in the editor.